# Java break out of for loop after result found

Tags: java

I have this class

```
public void findMedia(String title) {
    for(Media mediaByTitle : list) {
        if (mediaByTitle.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            System.out.print(mediaByTitle.toString());
        
        } else {
            System.out.print("Title does not exist\n"); 
            break;
        }
    }
    
}
```

What I want to do is stop the loop when the result is found.

I understand the logic it is searching every element of the list, however how I can it to print "Title does not exist" is nothing is found.

This will work fine to print the list if found, however if not found it is just a blank line.

```
public void findMedia(String title) {
    for(Media mediaByTitle : list) {
        if (mediaByTitle.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            System.out.print(mediaByTitle.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple different way to get the logic straight but I think I am out of braincells at the moment.

Comment: Easiest thing would be to `return;` if a match is found and add a `System.out.println("Nothing found");` after the `foreach`-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing would be to `return;` if a match is found and add a `System.out.println("Nothing found");` after the `foreach`-loop.

Notice that this an unusual use case. We would normally return a match (e.g. the index, or the `mediaTitle`, or a `boolean`). If we return a reference type, we could let the method return, for example, an [`Optional<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), then `return Optional.of(mediaByTitle)` if a match is found or an `Optional.empty()` if no match is found. We can then decide on the calling side, through the returned `Optional`, what to print.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two reasonable approaches to this.  The first is simply to return from the method once a match is found, and print the "not found" message after the loop.

```
public void findMedia(String title) {
    for(Media mediaByTitle : list) {
        if (mediaByTitle.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            System.out.print(mediaByTitle.toString());
            return;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Title does not exist"); 
}
```

A slightly cleaner way would be to have the method return the string, rather than print it, and do the printing outside of the method itself.

```
public String findMedia(String title) {
    for(Media mediaByTitle : list) {
        if (mediaByTitle.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            return mediaByTitle.toString();
        }
    }

    return "Title does not exist"; 
}
```

then, just write `System.out.println(findMedia("Whatever"));` to use this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always add a boolean flag.
Set it according to what logic you need, if the item was found in the list or not.
Something like this;

```
public void findMedia(String title) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    for(Media mediaByTitle : list) {
        if (mediaByTitle.getTitle().equals(title)) {
            System.out.print(mediaByTitle.toString());
            //change boolean value to true as item was found.
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    //since you want to print something when item is not in list, do something like this.
    if(!isFound) {
            System.out.print("Title does not exist\n"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `...print("...\n");`, we should use `...println("...")`.

Comment: I just copied the code from the OP. Just adding the boolean part that I am suggesting to that code. But yes, good point.

Comment: you don't need to iterate whole list if item was found at 5 out of 10

Answer (score 0):

Your most flexible option if you're searching a list of `Media` for a particular title would be a method that returns a reference to the master object already in the list. You could do something like:

```
public Media findMedia(String title) {
   return list.stream().filter(m -> m.getTitle().equals(title)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Or do the same with a `for` loop if you prefer